# Go: gRPC sync messages to client on longlive server-side stream connection

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I have only one server and a lot of clients which open a longlive connection to the server. The server will send a request to specific clients (identified by the IP) by a time table (like cron) and manually (so more than one request could run a the same time). But I want to wait for the response of the request.

Simple requests are the wrong direction, because the connection can only be opened by the client. So I switched to server-side streams. I used a subscriber model and it works well for async calls, but the `stream.Send()` will not wait and the client cannot send a response without ending the connection.

A bidirectional solution has the same problem with the direct response, but a possible solution. The solution would be async calls with ids. The server sends the request to the client with an id and adds a wait-for-response-entry in a queue on the server with the same id. I used this kind of solution in a JavaScript-WebSocket environment and it had a lot of its own problems (like orphan wait entries).

Is there a better solution than using two channels or a bidirectional channel with ids?

Comment: You might find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53098915/11810946) useful (a few other options are mentioned).

Comment: Nice, so gRPC has not this edge case (and other I need) natively. But the mentioned library `https://github.com/jhump/grpctunnel` has a reverse tunnel which is the right thing to solve this problem. But I also need to evaluate some websocket libraries (after gorilla is dead) and look for my edge cases. I think I am too spoiled by my old JS websocket library and don't know if there is a good enough ws lib for go or I need to change my architecture to work with gRPC.